# MySQL search from pipeline delimitated string

Tags: mysql

In MYSql 5.7 (i can't use PHP or similar language or other MySQL version) i have two table:

**Operators** and **OperatorsWork**

In the first table i have the ID and the name

In the second table i have a string with pipeline separeted IDs

Here you can find a DB Fiddle for test:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iTYVLJQgaNEs92rMQKgybP/1

Pratically i need to take the *IDOperators* column and match with *name* column

The expected result is comma separated values in this way:

1 - Name1, Name2, Name3

2 - Name2, Name3

3 - Name1, Name3

The original *IDOperators* was:

1 - 1|2|3

2 - 2|3

3 - 1|3

Many thanks

Comment: Normalize the schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in this way

```
SELECT  b.id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY a.id) Result
FROM    Operators a
        INNER JOIN OperatorsWork b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.id, REPLACE(b.IDOperators, '|', ',')) > 0
GROUP BY b.id
```